# Rails: complicated design choice: polymorphism? STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying different techniques while designing this application, which to me is very complicated as there are many solutions to chose from. Deciding which of these solutions is the best has become my full time job for the last few weeks.

### Background:

I have a `User` model which contains some very basic authentication functionality. The application will have three different types of users; admins, buyers, and sellers. The user type will be determined during sign up, where a check box will ask if the user is a seller. If the box is checked, the user is a seller, and if the box is unchecked, it's assumed their just a buyer. I would rather not have a drop down menu to select the user type (Buyer, Seller). Easy so far.

### Details:

Sellers have a profile, and users who visit the site will be able to browse through the different sellers and view their profile. Buyers do not have a profile, and should not be listed on the site for users to see. If that's not complicated enough, buyers should have the option to change their account type and become a seller. Similarly, sellers can change their account type and "deactivate" their seller account, removing them from the list of sellers.

### Design options:

**Single table inheritance**:

What I came up with when attempting to implement this using STI was suboptimal. I was faced with two options: a messy controller, which made the decision of what type of user to create based on the check box mentioned above (one controller - UsersController), or two different sign up forms that were identical (two controllers - BuyersController, SellersController).

**has_one or "has_none" Profile association**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile # only if the user_type or role is "seller"
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here I would use something like CanCan or declarative_authorization, and let the user chose his/her role via the check box mentioned above. This introduces a security risk, as there will be an admin role and I don't want this to be open for mass assignment.

I guess either way you look at it I'll have a messy controller with conditionals on how to create the user. Unless I choose to have two check boxes ("I am a seller," and "I am a buyer"), but this seems redundant. It also seems as though whichever design I choose, I'll be faced with some hackish solutions.

Maybe introduce some model that lies between the `User` and user type?

Any opinions?

Comment: Note that an edit was suggested changing your use of the word "authentication" to "authorization". I believe the correction to be accurate, but in this case IMO it's best if you decide.

Comment: (I'd also add that your previous, obviously-related questions change the nature of this question and its optimal answers. That said, I'm still not sure what the big deal is--if you want to create users from a single form, it's not a lot of extra work, you know?)

Comment: I was thinking about linking to my previous questions. However, this question has a more accurate and precise description of what the application needs to do. If I could, I'd throw away the older ones. Also, are you referring to my use of the word "authentication" in the description of the User model? There is no authorization going on in the User model (yet). Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I think the original editor was just pointing out that if there's authentication, it doesn't matter for this, and the discusion is kore about authorization, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really think you need either STI or Polymorphism. A single user model should suffice. I would add three methods to your user model (administrator?, buyer?, seller?) and also add scopes that will return only buyers, only sellers, or only admins.

In your case, it sounds like you have a real minimal number of roles for users (2 now, expanding to 3 with admins). I would probably use the technique Ryan discusses in the ["Embedded Associations"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) Railscast.

I've done something very similar in my latest project, and then used CanCan (in my case, the 2.0 alpha branch, as I find it simpler) on top of that. Your ability class would look something like this (in 2.0 syntax, but you can do the same with 1.x, I'm sure)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.seller?
      can :create, :profile
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I started to implement this solution while waiting for answers, and I'm really glad to hear other people (not just one person) suggest this route. This definitely seems like the way to go. Couldn't I just wrap up the admin?, buyer?, and seller? methods into one is_a?(role) method that checks the users roles? Similar to the way Ryan Bates does it in his CanCan Railscast.

Comment: sure. I liked the simplicity of direct methods without providing an argument.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any suggestions on securing the admin role via mass assignment? I want users to select their role, but limited to buyer and seller. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

So far it sounds like you have a flag that indicates their user type, or a column with type string, etc.

You haven't indicated any *behavior* that depends on this--not showing up in listings etc. can be handled with scopes. Admin can be handled with a flag.

I don't see the problem yet, at least not a problem of a few weeks scope.

Answer (score 0):

A 3rd option.

> ...buyers should have the option to change their account type and become
>   a seller. Similarly, sellers can change their account type and
>   "deactivate" their seller account, removing them from the list of
>   sellers.

Have you considered not allowing switching of accounts? If a buyer wants to become a seller, then they create a new "seller" account. It would work the same for seller to buyer. It would mean having 2 controllers for the signup, etc. but it would keep the separation you're looking for. If the two must be mutually exclusive you could do a rudimentary email check to verify the user doesn't already have an account and if they do, they must de-activate the existing account prior to creating a new one.

Comment: I actually thought about this quite a bit and decided not to go this route. Thanks for your comment!