# Rails employer and employee devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, sti

I am trying to figure out how to structure this please help:
I need users to be able to sign up as either an employer or employee. The employer basically is the company and the employees are the people employed at that job. I want to know how to keep a record of when/if the employee was hired and terminated from the job. Would a `has_many:through` assotiation work for this or better yet is there a gem that I am overlooking that could help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked into STI (Single Table Inheritance)?

Comment: STI would mean duplicate fields in separate tables which may not be used

Comment: Yasky, what's up with the "may not be used?"  Is this a homework question?  It's fine if it is; most people will still give you advice on solving the problem, but you might as well put all of your cards on the table.  Otherwise, you'll probably keep getting unusable answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic case of the hierarchical object model, so you have to think about this problem in terms of the *objects* involved and their *relationships* to each other. Think about the way a business works in real life:

Employer -> Employees NOT Employer -> Manager etc. -> Employees

A good example of this system model is that of GitHub. On GitHub, users can *belong* to Organisations. They can also create them and administrate them, managing members etc. (hiring and firing in your case). Therefore a much better way of modelling this system is having it be User-centric rather than a split of two different classes of User.

> As stated in a previous answer, Employers (or Businesses in this
>   sense) should not be considered as users of the system as they won't
>   be acting on the state of the program, users will. Therefore, I personally think STI is a
>   little overkill for this system model.

So...

**All** people employed in a business are employees, but not all employees have the *same level* of authority (Managers will have more authority than Junior employees for example). Therefore you should model a `Business`, which *has many* `Employee`s. Those `Employee`s will have varying levels of authority based on their position:

- can_hire?
- can_fire?
- etc.

You could also create a method that would tell you when this `Employee` was hired/fired. These could return a date/time if they were hired/fired or `nil` if not. `nil` in this sense would obviously imply they haven't yet been hired/fired.

When it comes to managing the abilities of different users, their level of authority is defined by what they can and cannot do. You can of course apply preset roles to this situation with a simple method that checks the above methods. For example:

```
def manager?
  self.can_hire? and self.can_fire?
end
```

You would then also define an ability that would allow the creation of a Business:

```
def can_create_business?
  self.manager?
end
```

Note: you can use scopes to achieve this elegantly.

You can also sub-class a basic User model for your roles, or create a Role class that defines the above methods and acts on a given User model. You can then create individual roles and subsets of roles.

Arguably, there are some cases where allowing the creation of employers/businesses and employees as separate entities that can both act on the state of the program are useful. If the `Business` can perform more than just simple administration functions then this might be worth it. In which case, I would still not consider the business as a User model. I would require a special user account be created along with the `Business` which would have a role of `Business Administrator` or something similar.

This model follows some of the most basic principles in programming and Computer Science as a whole, so I hope it sheds a little light on your problem. Of course there are a number of gems available that have this functionality built-in, namely **Devise** and **CanCan/CanTango**, although I would personally build this system myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think I will combine STI with has many through relationship.

I will first start by making a single table inheritance of Employers and Employees.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Employer < User
end

class Employee < User
end
```

Employer hires employees. One employer can have many employees and with employment come other related properties like `date_of_hire`, `designation`, `status`, `manager_id`, `department` etc. Hence I would model this as a separate object and hence store this information in a separate table. Let's call that `Employment`, shall we?

```
rails g model employment employer_id:integer, employee_id:integer, date_of_hire:date, designation:string, status:string, manager_id:integer
```

Let's establish relationships now.

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer # Foreign key options should not required because of User STI
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :manager,  :foreign_key => :manager_id,  :class_name => "User"
end

class Employee < User
  has_many :employments
  has_many :employers
  has_one  :manager,      :through     => :employments, :foreign_key => :manager_id
end

class Employer < User
  has_many :employments, :foreign_key => :employer_id
  has_many :employees,   :through     => :employments
end
```

Based on business rules we can implement elegant scopes.

```
class Employee < User
  ...
  scope :fired, :where => {:status => 'fired'}
  scope :recently_joined, :where => {:date_of_hire => 3.months.ago...Date.today}
  scope :developers, :where => {:designation => 'developer'}
  ... 
end
```

and...

```
Employee.recently_joined
Employee.recently_joined.developers
Employee.fired
```

Please understand that this is obviously not a tested code and may have some glitches.

### However!

I would highly encourage you to re-consider the need of modeling employers as users. From my personal experience, it turned out to be disaster in the future (May be I was inexperienced then but I won't really take that route again). I would really make separate models for Employer and Employee and establish relationships as above but with foreign_key and class_name attributes. The major reason is that for STI to work, in your domain, the employer and employee should have an "IS A" relationship with User. You might be tempted to think that it is an "IS A" relationship but also think whether it's the same "TYPE" of "IS A" relationship. In the application I worked on, it did not make sense and yet we settled with STI. The employers had completely different set of features, identity and treatment in the application from the employees. Although there was some data that was the same for both, it existed for different purposes and was used different. That is a reason enough (Single Responsibility) to model them separately. STI is a tricky tool that can solve a problem. But use it incorrectly and it will create more problems than what it would solve.

Comment: I've found that in almost all cases STI is a bit hacky and eventually gets pulled out and refactored away.

Comment: We're using STI quite effectively to differentiate between different types of companies in our app. There are no Company rows which are not a subclass of Company, such as AwesomeCompany or NotSoGreatCompany. Each type of Company also has a related profile, such as AwesomeCompanyProfile, to store information unique to that type of company. It works pretty well for us.

Comment: @CalebThompson The case you have mentioned sounds like a good example of when to use STIs. All the STI subclasses you have share the same kind of "IS A" relationship with company. And I guess I said the same in my answer above. But modeling employers (which are usually companies) and employees as Users doesn't seem right as an Employer does not share the same kind of "IS A" relationship as an Employee does with the User. However, it always depends on your business rules. But from my personal experience it's _almost_ always a mistake to do that.

Comment: Chirantan, I agree with you that Employee/Employer are likely sufficiently different that they should not use STI. I was directing my comment to @KevinBedell whose comment made it sound like there is _never_ a case for STI.

Comment: I agree with you @CalebThompson, there are cases where it makes sense but they are very rare. I was happy with my decision to use STI only once out of the 5 times I have used it. It's not that it's totally useless.

Comment: @CalebThompson I'm glad you've found a case where it's useful. I agree that there can be times it's useful, but I've actually never seen it implemented successfully. I've seen it put in and then ripped out later more than once. But you're correct in that I should probably not have made such a sweeping statement. Thanks for sharing your success story.

Answer (score 0):

Just use has_many, :through. It will get the job done. Say you need to get all the active employees for a single company you can do

```
class Employers   
  has_many  :hired_employees, :through => :employments, 
            :class_name => "Employees", 
            :source => :employee, 
            :conditions => ['employment.status= ?',"hired"] 
end
```

Then you can do `Employers.first.hired_employees`. You can add more and use different conditions so that you can get 'terminated', 'dismissed' etc.

Of course this assumes you have a third model called Employment where it belongs to Employee and Employer. Your Employee and Employment classes could look like this:

```
class Employee
  has_many :employments
end

class Employment
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :employer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, you may need the following model: User, Job, Assignment, Role

```
class User
    ... some devise declarations here ...
    ... some role here. rolify gem is my suggestion ...
    scope :employee, :where => {user.has_role? :employee}
    scope :employer, :where => {user.has_role? :employer}
    has_many :jobs, :through => :assignments 
    has_many :assignments 
end

class Job
    belongs_to :user # employer
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :assignments # employee
end

class Assignment
   belongs_to :job
   belongs_to :user # employee
   def fired?
       ... stuff to check if the employee is fired
   end
   def hired?
       ... stuff to check if the employee is hired
   end
end
```

Pros:

- you can add more roles such as manager, admin ... easily. Using rolify gem or you can just create the role model for yourself
- the assignment class will stored anything you need to store such as fired, hired about the employee
- since the roles are clearly predefined, access control can be added easily using authorization gem such as cancan.

Cons:

- Using this model, use must check whether the current user you are working on is an employer or an employee before doing anything else. However, this can be easily be checked using roles

For simplicity, you can use rails_app_composer gem to generate the initial app with devise, cancan and rolify installed.

NOTE: this answer is based on many similar questions such as: 
[Polymorphism or STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907703/rails-complicated-design-choice-polymorphism-sti)